# Does core.clj have to contain -main function to be run from command line?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When using Leiningen to create a project, does the core.clj file have to contain the -main function (the auto-generated one when the app is created) in order to run the program with the command `lein run`? Do all functions I create have to be called inside -main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not have to be in core.clj.  You can put your `-main` function wherever you like, so long as you tell lein where to look for it in your `defproject` in project.clj.

```
(defproject myproject "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :main ^:skip-aot myproject.other-name-space)
```

This will tell lein to load `myproject.other-name-space` as its primary namespace when it loads the repl and when it looks for a `-main` class.  If you have `-main` class in two places, lein will use the one you specify here in `defproject`.  You do not need to place all your program code in the `-main` class, you simply use it as a starting point.